# Image with picasso and Json parameter in Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest, picasso

I have a rest server where I need download image with picasso.
I need pass a json parameter to rest server method. That rest server method is something as:

Rest server method:

```
public Bitmap GetServerBitmap(Jsonobject param){
   Bitmap bitmap=get_bitmap();
   return bitmap;
}
```

Android client method:
Here I need a example of the code to call the rest server method at line "MyGetServerBitmap".

```
    private void downloadimage(final int nr) {
    String url = Common.getServerURL() + "\"GetServerBitmap\"";
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    ja.put(nr);

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("_parameters", ja);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //will return a bitmap from rest server
    Bitmap mybitmap=MyGetServerBitmap(url, jsonBody); I need a code using picasso to do it
}
```

How could I code this "MyGetServerBitmap" method?

I have tried the next:

```
private Bitmap MyGetServerBitmap(String url, JsonObject jsonBody){
Bitmap bmp;
//Where I pass json parameter in picasso?
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .error(R.drawable.image_name)
    .into(bmp);
    return bmp;   
}
```

But I can't see no option to pass json parameter.

Regards, Luiz

Answer (score 1):

You do not see one, because there is not one.  There is a good reason for that. Picasso uses the `URI` as the key for the cache to determine if it needs to load a given images again.  Sending requests to the same URI with different payloads would create problems with the cache.  Likely, you'd see all your images be same -- which ever one was loaded first.  If your server supports sending the parameter as a query parameter instead of a JSON payload, such as `http://myserver.place/GetServerBitmap/?nr=imageparam`, the picasso will work for you because it fits neatly in an `URI`.

You would be able to get the behavior you want out of Picasso if you implement a custom [`Downloader`](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Downloader.java) to unpack URI's into JSON payloads.

Comment: Thank you. It was a good answer. But I am lost how to do a custom downloader with json paremeters in Picasso. I have search on net but there is  no sample with Picasso.

Comment: The rest server is not mine has the next requirement. For sample, if the serverf function is(code in delphi): function TServerMethods1.EchoAttribute(Key: String; Obj: TJSONObject): String;  The server requierements say that:"If you want to pass multiple parameter values in the request content, then you need to put them in a JSON array in the correct order, and make that array be the value of a JSON object pair, with the key "_parameters". The resulting JSON object should be represented as a string and set as the content of the request, looking like this:
{"_parameters":["Param1", "Param2"]}

Comment: A sample of request: POST /datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/EchoAttribute/Attr1 HTTP/1.1
....*additional headers*...
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

{"Attr1":"ValueToReturn"}

Comment: With PHP: <?php
 $cid = array( "typ" => "AX" , "id" => 1 , "fields" => array ( "FId" => 4 , "FD" => "LI" ) );
 $url  = 'http://localhost:8080/restserv/%22AddCid%22/' ;
 $ch = curl_init() ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ( "Accept: application/json" , "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" ) ) ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_HEADER , FALSE ) ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true ) ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_POST , TRUE ) ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_URL , $url ) ;
 curl_setopt( $ch , CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , json_encode( $cid) ) ;
 $result = curl_exec( $ch ) ;
 ?>